# Load test execution time in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest, load-testing

I have created a set of tests in visual studio ultimate for load testing.

I am using MsTest for the testing:-
The execution time of the tests is part of the output from the load tests.
I was wondering if the [TestInitialize] time was included in the test time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestInitialize runs before each test, so no, it's not included.

[TestInitializeAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx)